# How to insert path between absoluteURL and parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin

My url looks like this: https://test.com/test#someParameter

And i want to insert `"/site"` between the url and the parameter without string operations, because using string operations on urls are not best practise.

The final url should look like this: https://test.com/test/site#someParameter

I tried using .apply but it didn't work:

```
URI(url).apply { path += "/site" }.toString()
```

Comment: what if you change apply to let?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a safe way to do it is using `urllib`

```
import urllib

args = {"site": "site", "param": "some_parameter"}
url = "https://test.com/test/{}#{}".format(urllib.urlencode(args))
```